# SSRS IIF expression with Time

Tags: reporting-services

I have date in the format 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 in the database.
How can I write an IIF expression in SSRS iif date=1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 then display null or else display another field duration value.
How can I get the colons working in iif expressions in ssrs?
I am getting an error field when I run the report.
Can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the expression like this:

```
=IIf(Fields!MyDate.Value <= "1/1/1900", Nothing, Fields!MyDate.Value)
```

Edit:

You can also use

```
=IIf(Fields!MyDate.Value <= "1/1/1900", 0, Fields!MyDate.Value)
```

And then you can set the formatting to:

```
=IIf(Fields!MyDate.Value <= "1/1/1900", "mm:ss tt", "d")
```

You can use whatever format string you want here. "d" is short for the standard "Short Date" format.

Comment: Thank you very much. This has helped me! But is there a way I can display 000:00:00 instead of Nothing in the iif expression?